# Subtring to get date in android

Tags: android, substring

I have a String `Sun, 26 Mar 2017 10:28:06 +0700`.

I want to get `26 Mar 2017` in Android.

Thanks

Comment: yourString.substring(5, 15)

Comment: Don't try to use `String` manipulation for that. Convert the format as shown in the links provided at the top of your question.